# Bar Button Item Tint Color not working

Tags: swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance, tint

As you can see in the attached image, the bar button has its tint color set to red, however it is displayed in black. I think this is due to the text color still being black? Is there a way to change this?

I changed the tint color of this bar button item, the navigation bar it is in, and the `UIBarButtonItem.appearance()`, as well as `UINavigationBar.appearance()`. Closing the popover and reopening it changes the color.

**EDIT**

In the hierarchy below the bar button has the correct tint color (no text), the label has correct tint and text colors however the label has different tint and text colors. Text color is still the one from the old theme and does not update until the view is dismissed and reopened.

However holding down the button causes it to flash in the new color, and then fade back to normal.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a piece of code I use to style `UIBarButtonItem`:

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {

   func style(tint color: UIColor, font f: UIFont? = nil) {
       let font = f ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.systemFontSize)
       tintColor = color
       let atts = [
           NSAttributedStringKey.font : font,
           NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : color
       ]
       setTitleTextAttributes(atts, for: .normal)
   }

}
```

This should've been the end of it but attempting to change the title attributes and tint color repeatedly (e.g. on button action) reveals nothing happens unless the bar button item's title changes. This is weird behaviour but an easy workaround will be to do just that, change the title by adding and removing extra space at the end of the title like:

```
// Hack!!! adds and removes an empty space to the title to 
// force the bar item reset title attributes.
let title: String = barItem.title ?? ""
barItem.title = title.hasSuffix(" ") ? String(title.dropLast()) : title + " "
```

Comment: Color is still different for tint (What I actually want) and font color (which I cannot change). Same as in the screenshot above.

Comment: @Hans where did you try calling it?

Comment: Currently trying to reproduce it in a sample app. It is being called in a function called by a tap gesture recognizer from a custom uiview

Comment: Can you share your sample app?

Comment: Currently not able to reproduce it in another app. I don’t really want to share my main app.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce it. Surprisingly the changes are visible when you keep the button tapped but falls back when you let go, I'll edit my answer with the solution. Here is what I would do, remove the bar button and create new one (which will get rid off previous configuration you have). then call the above method.

Comment: Thank yo so much! I actually tried deleting and recreating the button, but after changing the style on the entire app. That did not work either, but your solution does. Took me ~12 hours Ringer here. One should probably create a UIKit bug report.