# Calling setTitleTextAttributes on UIBarButtonItem does not have any impact on iOS 11

Tags: ios11, uibarbuttonitem, navigationbar

I am using an appearance proxy in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` to set `UIBarButtonItem` title font across the project like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([
                NSAttributedStringKey.font: customFont
            ]
            , for: .normal)
```

What I would like to do is to change this font based on user choice?
So upon the user choosing a font I store it in `UserDefaults` and I send a local notification to those view controllers I know have `UIBarButtonItems` and I reset each directly like this:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems?.forEach { $0.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: ...], for: .normal) }
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems?.forEach { $0.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: ...], for: .normal) }
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font: customFont], for: .normal)
```

This works as expected in iOS 10 but in iOS 11 it doesn't have an immediate impact on either left, right or back bar button items.

The back bar button item gets adjusted to the new font if a view controller is popped and then pushed again to the navigation stack - the bar button items don't change until the next app run.

I am naturally doing the same thing with navigation bar title so in the AppDelegate:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: ...
    ]
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            NSAttributedStringKey.font : ...
        ]
    }
```

And in each view controller I reset these values again and titles instantly change font.

I tried to set bar button items title text attributes to the new font in each control state, namely: `[.normal, .highlighted, .disabled]` with no luck.

I also tried to set `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` to a new instance of `UIBarButonItem` hoping this will have the new font but the button disappears completely :D

Last thing I tried was to call `setNeedsDisplay` and `layoutIfNeeded` on the navigation bar but still nothing happens.

A sample project of the case could be found [here](https://github.com/aakhedr/BarButtonItem)

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48975439/bar-button-item-tint-color-not-working), it works well for me

Answer (score 0):

Here's a super hacky mechanism to work around what appears to be an obvious bug (or undocumented optimization):

```
    for controlState in [UIControlState.disabled, .highlighted, .normal] {

        self.changeBarButtonFont(barButtonItem: self.updateButton, font: font, controlState: controlState)

        self.changeBarButtonFont(barButtonItem: self.selectButton, font: font, controlState: controlState)
    }


private func changeBarButtonFont(barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem, font: UIFont, controlState: UIControlState) {
    barButtonItem.title = barButtonItem.title! + " "

    barButtonItem.setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : font], for: controlState)

    DispatchQueue.main.async
    {
        barButtonItem.title = barButtonItem.title?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces)
    }
}
```

Note that this does not work 100% as rapid taps on the 'Change font' won't register. But perhaps you could work this out?